# Entity Framework singularize/pluralize not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF 6, when we generate the models (dbmx) from our database, we have the checkbox checked that states:

> Pluralize or singularize generated object names

However, when the classes are generated, the name of each class is the exact name of the table, and its properties (whether a db type or db set) are the exact name of their respective table as well.

Basically, everything is pluralizing...

```
public virtual DbSet<Documents> Documents { get; set; } // Shoud be of type 'Document'
public virtual Images Images { get; set; } // should be of type 'Image', and named 'Image' as well
```

What am I missing here? Seems like EF just isn't naming things correctly.

**Edit**

I've tested this with singular and plural table names. As mentioned above, the generated code mimics exactly what the table names are. If the table name is `Documents`, then the type generated in C# is `Documents`... The type *should* be `Document` though.

In another solution, the generated code takes the plural table name `Documents`, and generates a type called `Document` out of it. *THIS* is the expected behavior for our new solution... but it's not working that way for some reason.

Comment: What are the names of the tables in the database? Document and Image or Documents and Images?

Comment: Edit added, tested with both plural and singular table names. The code generated mimics exactly what the table name is.

Comment: I think I remember coming across this at some point. Does your database have a mix of singular and plural names? I think that's what causes this behavior.

Comment: We have other databases with a mixture of singular and plural table names, yet the edmx entities were typed and named as we expected. I thought the naming convention came from the underlying relationship between the tables, yet that doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: What you did to solve this?